# How to list all autoload paths in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3, autoload

How do you list all of the autoload paths in Rails?

In Rails console when I do this, it only lists the custom paths added to the config:

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.9)
1.9.3p194 :001 > MyRailsApp::Application.config.autoload_paths
=> []
```

Answer (score 17, accepted):

*Update: please see Laura's answer using ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths below. I've left this answer here as an alternate method.*

In `Rails::Engine` which is included in the Rails application's module, there is the following method:

```
def _all_autoload_paths
  @_all_autoload_paths ||= (config.autoload_paths + config.eager_load_paths + config.autoload_once_paths).uniq
end
```

So, you could either do:

```
(MyRailsApp::Application.config.autoload_paths + MyRailsApp::Application.config.eager_load_paths + MyRailsApp::Application.config.autoload_once_paths).uniq
```

or:

```
[:autoload_paths, :eager_load_paths, :autoload_once_paths].collect{|m|MyRailsApp::Application.config.send(m)}.flatten.uniq
```

or just:

```
MyRailsApp::Application._all_autoload_paths
```

The default result in Rails 3.2.9 is:

```
["/path/to/my_rails_app/app/assets", "/path/to/my_rails_app/app/controllers", "/path/to/my_rails_app/app/helpers", "/path/to/my_rails_app/app/mailers", "/path/to/my_rails_app/app/models"]
```

This should include all the autoload paths that were added by other gems and custom load paths.

Answer (score 26):

You can access all the autoload paths through `ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths`

Invoke it from console or run `rails r 'puts ActiveSupport::Dependencies.autoload_paths'` from command line.

More info here (For Rails 4, but it applies to Rails 3 as well):
http://guides.rubyonrails.org/autoloading_and_reloading_constants.html#autoload-paths

Comment: Works in Rails 5 as well

Comment: Work in Rails 6 as well!

Answer (score 4):

```
Rails.application.instance_variable_get(:"@_all_autoload_paths")
```